# How to fix this sink

Tags: bathroom, sink

My bathroom sink drain was slow in clearing so I used this chemical drain opener that has worked for me past on other sinks and tubs. https://www.homedepot.com/p/Instant-Power-128-oz-Hair-and-Grease-Drain-Opener-1972/302373121

However, this time I ended up with damage. I thought my sink was of metal but now I am not sure. The paint is damaged and it reveals a discoloration with maybe wood beneath or some alloy.

Can I fix this by simply painting this over? If yes what kind of paint.[image]

Comment: Looks like the acid used has eaten the coating on the sink. I assume it is metal or vitreous or porcelain in a color. But matching the color and being durable are going to be hard. You might be able to visit a bathroom showroom and see if they have suggestions, or know of a way to color the Homax kit as in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used HOMAX Tough as Tile for years. It's an epoxy coating that will stick to just about any clean surface. You can pick this kit up for about $25. It has everything you need for the job (Tri-Sodium Phosphate, Brush, Gloves and Paint). Follow the directions and especially the cleaning section in order to remove soap scum, etc. The process requires 2 coats and will take about 2-3 days to dry but you will be amazed at the end result which will be a candy shell appearance like porcelain. For optimum results, remove the drain for the work and then re-install it when the job is finished. The fumes will need to be addressed by ventilation and the odor is also a consideration.

**Note: This kit comes in almond or white. It also comes with a spray can option which I don't recommend. The spray gets all over everything and takes a long time to dry.**

[image: Homax Tough as Tile]

Comment: But Isn’t using this a problem since the existing color is black?

Comment: It is a problem if you want it to remain black. It only comes in two colors. I have used it over colored tiles and it worked great in two coats. It's an epoxy, so if you want to use some oil-based primer after cleaning the sink it wouldn't hurt anything. Epoxy paints cover exceptionally well.

Comment: So instead of using this product, I can use an oil based paint on the sink?

Comment: You could use an oil-based primer and topcoat. I can't suggest it because I don't know what the end result would be. I have never attempted it because I have had such good success with HOMAX. I would definitely still suggest that you clean the sink thoroughly with TSP. Perhaps you should ask another question in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

**Got lemons?  Make lemonade!**

Maybe this is a crazy idea but here goes.

Your cleaner is basically lye.  By the original color of your sink and the color it turned I would guess it is either bronze or patinated copper.  The copper color it changed to is not terrible; the only problem is that it does not match and it is irregular looking.

Roll with it.  Get another bottle of the same stuff and treat the entire sink with a smooth coat.   Spread it around with a sponge brush.  Wear gloves and goggles.  Let the drain cleaner sit on the dark areas and do them like it did the spot near the drain.  Then rinse and buff it out.

You will have a copper colored sink.  It is not going to look worse than it does now.  It will cost a bottle of drain cleaner and a sponge brush to try.  If you get away with it and the sink looks good, you are set.

If it looks terrible, it does not close the door to trying something else with the sink.  On the theory that alkaline turned it bright, you could try acid to turn it dark (lemon juice?).

If you do try this please post image.